# Consume kubernetes secret from KubernetesPodOperator (Airflow)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I'm setting up an Airflow environment on Google Cloud Composer for testing. I've added some secrets to my namespace, and they show up fine.

```
secret_token = secret.Secret(
    deploy_type='env',
    deploy_target='SQL_CONN',
    secret='m-secrets',
    key='token')

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_set_controlm_secret_kubernetes_pod',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:

  kubernetes_secret_vars_ex = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='ex-kube-secrets',
        name='ex-kube-secrets',
        image='eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT/$DOCKER_IMG:latest',
        namespace='default',
        cmds=['python'],
        arguments=['call_api.py'],
        secrets=[secret_token]
  )
```

As you can se above, I am running a docker image which call my **call_api.py** program, I would like to print the secret passed via the KubernetesPodOperator as below :

*call_api.py*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
print($secret_token) ====> how can I do this ?
```

Can't find any valuable resource on the documentation...

Comment: Do you need the secret to be printed within the *call_api.py*? According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/#verify-the-secret), you can access the secrets using `kubectl describe secrets/your-secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified deploy_type to be env, airflow will add the secret you selected to the container's environment.

You have multiple options for reading from an environment. The way via the default libraries is os.environ , which gives you a dictionary of the current environment variables.

import os

print(os.environ['SQL_CONN'])
However, there are other options if you want to do configuration this way. We use dynaconf for our airflow deployments, which gives you a settings object that you can read environment variables from as long as they have been made with a DYNACONF_ prefix.